# Value of an array after code execution

Tags: java, arrays

I have to fill in the array with the values that would be stored after the following code is executed:

```
int[] list = {2, 18, 6, -4, 5, 1};
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = list[i] + (list[i] / list[0]);
}
```

For `list[0]` I got the value 3, which was correct.
For `list[1]` I got the value 27 which was wrong.
For `list[2]` I got 9 which was also wrong.

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong? The length of the array is 6, right?

Comment: The length of the array is 5

Comment: @AlexMontoro no, the length is 6, the max index is 5

Comment: 18+(18/2)=27 is correct for list[1]

Comment: Length is 6, right

Comment: Which would be the right output for list[2]?

Comment: those values are correct, what do you want to do

Comment: @ina what values do you expect and what values do you get?

Comment: [If only we could run the code...](https://ideone.com/a9I4O2).

Comment: in your way which one is correct output

Comment: @Stultuske You're right, my fault sorry

Comment: list[0] is 3 after the first loop iteration

Comment: "Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?" No, because we don't know how you arrived at those answers.

Comment: Indeed - "I got" is very unclear in terms of "I would expect" vs "that's what I saw when I ran the code".

Comment: @Stultuske I expect to get 24 for list[2]. You can check out the explanation by Eran.

Comment: @ina26 since that is exactly what the code you've shown us returns, what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list [0] = list[0] + (list[0]/list[0]) = 2 + 2/2 = 3
list [1] = list[1] + (list[1]/list[0]) = 18 + 18/3 = 24
list [2] = list[2] + (list[2]/list[0]) = 6 + 6/3 = 8
list [3] = list[3] + (list[3]/list[0]) = -4 - 4/3 = -5
list [4] = list[4] + (list[4]/list[0]) = 5 + 5/3 = 6
list [5] = list[5] + (list[5]/list[0]) = 1 + 1/3 = 1
```

You forgot that `list[0]` changed from 2 to 3 in the first iteration, which affects the result of all the following iterations.

Comment: list[i] = list[i] + (list[i] / list[0]); so for the second item it will be 18/2 + 18=27

Comment: @AnupamBiswas with the original value of list[0], yes, but, re-read Eran's post.

Comment: As per the calculation , last part is list[0] , so it will be first value

Comment: @AnupamBiswas And after first iteration, `list[0] = 3`.

Comment: @AnupamBiswas `list[0]` equals 2 only prior to the first iteration of the loop. After the first iteration, it equals 3.

Comment: @AnupamBiswas However, list[0] is redefined with a value of 3

Answer (score 1):

```
  int[] list = {2,18,6,-4,5,1};
        for ( int i = 0; i<list.Length; i++){
            list [i] = list[i] + (list[i]/list[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(list [i]);
        }
```

Output:
3
24
8
-5
6
1

After first iteration list[0]=3;
you can check my code here:
http://rextester.com/TJQTH40178

Comment: i was in execution mode so its Lil delay

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in code...

just print out values after complete execution of your logic.

```
public class ArrayTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] list = { 2, 18, 6, -4, 5, 1 };
       for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
           list[i] = list[i] + (list[i] / list[0]);
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(list[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer :

3
24
8
-5
6
1